# What does the lower dimension mean?

Tags: drawings

4.3 is the diameter of the hole in mm. But I don't understand the 4- part. Usually that's like a screw size but I haven't seen it like this before.

edit: as one commenter said I think it's just to indicate there are 4 holes

[image]

Comment: I guess it is the nominal size followed by the actual size with allowable tolerance.

Comment: I agree with @r13 although this is non standard. Another possibility is it’s a typo of 4 X if this appears in four places - which might be clear from context?

Comment: 4.3 mm = 0.169 inches. Since the other dimension also seems to be in both units, I guess the "4 -" is something different, for example "4 locations."

Comment: Another guess - 4.3mm is the "fine tolerance" clearance size for a 4mm bolt. See https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/iso-metric-thread-drill-tap-size-d_2045.html.

Comment: @31141 Please post a larger area of the drawing, to include more details that having similar notation, can help to identify the labelling/drafting convention the designer/drafter was using.

Comment: Context, context, context!  As r13 says, we need to see more of drawing to be definitive.  Is there 4 holes and 3 without dimensions?